# How to get/set the bonding box in google map?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

How can I get/set the bonding box of a Google map? I know how to create map using center and zoom, but I need a way to save the view of map based on its boxing and the recreate the same view later using the map bonds (NE and SW of map)

Any idea how I can do this?

I am using MVC 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the map.getBounds() function which returns a LatLngBounds object.  From this you can then use getNorthEast() and getSouthWest() to get the coordinates you want.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

If you need those LatLng objects to then be strings (for inserting to your DB or writing to a cookie or whatever), just use the toString() function on them.

```
strNE = NE.toString();
strSW = SW.toString();
```

So let's assume you write these to a cookie or use Ajax to write these to your DB.  Once you get them out of the cookie/DB later, you can then just use those for setting the center of the map:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(SW, NE);
map.fitBounds(bounds);  // or maybe try panToBounds()
```

All these functions are documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference